# Pulling HTML Value using JQuery .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I've looked through many post on SO and Google, and I imagine I'm missing a step or piece of understanding about .val() As it stands my code below returns Undefined in the . Any tips on getting the actual button value is greatly appreciated.

Simply put I have an HTML button, I want to pull the value of that button on click and display it.

HTML

```
<button type="button" name="criterianButton" id="english" class="searchButton" value="English">English</button>
```

JQuery

```
var buttonValues = $('#english').val();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
            $('#resultsView').append('<div class="searchResults">'+buttonValues+'</div>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Put the first line within document ready handler and it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because your jQuery selector:

```
var buttonValues = $('#english').val();
```

is being executed before the document is ready. So, like some of the other answers have said, you need to put it in your $(document).ready() call, and it'll work. You're basically trying to find the value before the browser knows it's there. Here's some sample code that has it working correctly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var buttonValues = $('#english').val();
    $('button').click(function(){
        alert("the value of buttonValues = " + buttonValues);
    });
});​
```

And here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tgsm4/)

If you have any other questions, feel free to comment and ask!

Answer (score 3):

Just put `var buttonValues = $('#english').val();` in `$(document).ready()`.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var buttonValues = $('#english').val();
    $('button').click(function(){
            $('#resultsView').append('<div class="searchResults">'+buttonValues+'</div>');
    });
});​
```

DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/qmMhJ/

Comment: Thank you for the help and keeping the <div> append.